# Ascertain method call order in a Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I searched stackoverflow and couldn't find a good answer on this.

If I create a class:

```
class Test():
     def foo(self):
        pass

     def bar(self):
        if bar() is called before foo(), then throw exception
```

is there a way that when someone creates an instance of class and accidentally calls `bar()` before `foo()` like this:

```
a = Test()
a.bar()
```

Python will throw an exception telling the user to call `foo()` first.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: you can use a flag to check if foo was called...you can also put the code of `foo` in `__init__` so it's called when _creating_ the object.

Comment: Or you can make it so that calling `bar` before `foo` is not an error.

Comment: Or you can make `bar` require a "key" which can be obtained from `foo` (like video games do to have you visit places in the correct order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to indicate that `foo()` has occurred when calling `bar()`
Something like the following could work:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_called = False

    def foo(self):
        self.foo_called = True

    def bar(self):
        assert self.foo_called,"Error: foo() needs to be called first" # Or another error message
```

Ideally, your code would handle this for you. If you only need to call `foo()` once then it can be in `__init__`, otherwise you might be able to call it in `bar()`

Answer (score 1):

Just call `foo` when you instantiate the object of class `Test`

```
class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()

    def foo(self):
        print('foo called')

    def bar(self):
        print('bar called')

t = Test()
t.bar()
foo called
bar called
```

Comment: I see what you did and it makes sense, but what if the user explicitly calls `foo()` again without realizing that it is already instantiated in the `__init__` method? I believe there needs to be some sort of code that needs to handle this edge case

Comment: The  code within foo can be changed to handle a case that if it is called again, it doesn't do anything bad